# How do I make text raggedright inside all miniboxes?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, environments, minipage

I have been looking at re-defining minipage so that it is always raggedright  but that looks problematic because of the optional arguments. 
I have a long document which uses lots of minipages. I would like to make them all raggedright inside. Is there any way to do this?

The code below does not do what I want because it is not raggedright inside the minipage

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\raggedright

\begin{minipage}{0.4\linewidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\@minipagerestore` hook:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\let\@minipagerestore=\raggedright
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to patch `\@iiiminipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@iiiminipage}
  {\@setminipage}
  {\@setminipage\raggedright}
  {}
  {}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth}
\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the \@minipagerestore hook. It worked beautifully. Thank you so much!